# How to model date at different precision as either year or month/year or day/month/year in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, date

I want to give the possibility to a user to enter a date at different precision:

- only as year or
- as month and year or
- as day, month and year.

What is the best way to do this in Cocoa (and store it in Core Data).
How can i validate the input in a NSTextField (is a NSTextField the best option)?
How can i search for corresponding items based on search field entries in the same manner?

Comment: check out NSDateComponents

Answer (score 0):

An NSDate will always have the year, month, day and time. You can use the code below to return a date with the specified values:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year Month:(NSInteger)month Day:(NSInteger)day {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.year = year;
    components.month = month;
    components.day = day;
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

If you want to change the display of the date, you can use NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"]; // shows only year
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"]; //shows month & year
```

To convert the date into a string using the formatter use:

```
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

read more on Date Formatting here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: In my usecase it is common that only the year is known to the person that enters the data. So i cannot assume a month or day, these may be incorrect. So NSDate cannot be used?

Comment: NSDate can be used, you can simply put your own month and date. e.g. if a user inputs 2013 as the year, you can simply do [self dateWithYear:2013 Month:1 Day:1]

Comment: Afterwards to display only the year, format it with the NSDateFormatter as shown above

Comment: Yes, but i could no longer decide if an event happened really on 1-1-2013 or if it happened someday in 2013 unknown to me but set to 1-1 because i would have to set it to something :)

Comment: There might as well be other dates in the same collection, where the exact date is known to the user and entered into the system. And should of course also be displayed.